# Проблем погрузки классов при @import

Tags: css, css3, vue.js, style, vue-router

Есть несколько страниц `vue` с одинаковыми классами стилей. Решил перенести стили в один файл и подключать к каждой странице отдельно.
Проблема в том, что иногда классы стилей не загружаются, при перезагрузке страницы все хорошо. Редко, но заметно.

```
<template>
.....
</template>

<script>
.....
</script>

<style>
@import './css/style.css';
</style>
```

Есть ли варианты решения этой проблемы?

Не хотелось бы в каждом компоненте копипастить стили.

***UPD***

Замечено при переходу на эту страницу, где импортированы стили (использую [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/))

```
this.$router.push('/reg/step-2');
```

Comment: Стили у вас применяются на все компоненты. Потому что вы не указали область видимости через оператор scoped.  Подробнее в [официальной документации](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/ru/guide/scoped-css.html#%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BEn%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-n%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B3n%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8n%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: @Adrug с этим понятно, проблема в том что стили не всегда применяются к компоненту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка заключалась в конфликте стилей.
Добавил оператор `scoped` в каждом компоненте, и проблема разрешилась.